# What's the name of this statement?

Tags: functions, soft-question, terminology

I saw the next statement in a math meme:

$\forall A:\emptyset\neq A\implies\exists(f:A\to\bigcup A):\forall B\in A, f(B)\in A$

What is the name of such statement? If it has one

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Comment: This is provably false: if you take $A = \{\emptyset\}$ so that $\bigcup A = \emptyset$, then $A \neq \emptyset$, but there are no functions $f : A \to \bigcup A$. It becomes a version of the axiom of choice, if you add a condition that the members of $A$ are non-empty and change the last $A$ to $B$.

Comment: ... out of interest, where did you see this "meme"?

Comment: @Rob Arthan thank you for your answer. I saw the meme on Facebook if I remember correctly.

Comment: I see: I think the meme must have suffered in transcription $\ddot{\smile}$.